# How to make condition to find certain key value on Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a text file which contains bunch of teams, and stadiums. It can easily be added into a list or a dictionary. I have a software that fetches data from a website. If for example, when it gets the "Team1" value which let's say is "Arsenal" and i have already "Arsenal" in the dictionary and its key is the stadium value of it, how do i make a condition to check "If the Team1 value that was received is "xxxxx", search for it in the dictionary/list whatever, and find it's k value?

Comment: I assume you want to get value From Dictionary, only if key exist.Dictionary has ContainsKey method,ie.if(dict.ContainsKey("Arsenal"))
       {
Console.WriteLine(dict[Arsenal]) //will return stadium value.

Comment: I want like this: If it exists in the dictionary KEY (team name) then give me this key's value (stadium name)

Comment: Interesting! I will try it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to get value from Dictionary,only if Key Exists.Dictionary has ContainsKey method,

```
     //dict is a dictionary  
    if(dict.ContainsKey("Arsenal")) { 
    Console.WriteLine(dict[Arsenal]); //will return stadium value
    }
```

Comment: [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is better as it skips second lookup...